# editing already run migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, migration

A bit of a newb question:

After running a migration say add_images_to_projects

and adding the necessary columns, types, etc

and then running rake db:migrate

If I changed my mind about something regarding the migration, could I just edit the migration and run `rake db:migrate` again? Or would that cause something to break/is it not advised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I changed my mind about something regarding the migration, could I
>   just edit the migration and run rake db:migrate again?

You have to follow these steps

1. Do **`rake db:rollback`** OR **`rake db:migrate:down`**
2. Edit your changes and
3. Do **`rake db:migrate`** again.

This will let your changes reflect in the **`DB`**

If you already have **`some data`** in the **`DB`** and worried about **`losing`** it,then i would suggest you
to **`create another migration file`** which will reflect the changes in the **`DB`** with out **`losing of data`**

Comment: Yeah I ended up doing that, but was curious about what would happen otherwise or why its not advised?

Comment: @user3597950 What is not advised? Please elaborate.

Comment: If changed the migration manually and then ran rake db:migrate would that do anything? Or why is that not the way to do it?

Comment: @user3597950 That is not the way to do it.If you are just editing the `migration file` and doing `rake db:migrate`,that would trigger you the `error`.So before doing that you have to do `rake db:rollback` to revert back the previous migration.